# i am working on application and i got this notify() error

Tags: php, laravel

> *Call to a member function notify() on null?
>   *Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
>   Call to a member function notify() on null

### *Controllers\UserController.php

```
public function store3(Request $request) 
{
    $request->session()->flush();
    return redirect('home');
}
public function check(Request $request)
{ 
    $request->validate( [ ' => 'required|string|max:255', ]);
    $student_id = $request->input('student_id');
    $query = DB::select("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `student_id` = 
'$student_id'") ;
    return view('auth.studentregistraionStatus',['query'=>$query]);
}
public function notificationmail(Request $request)
{
    $student_id = session('student_id');
    $user = User::where('id','=','1')->first();
    $user->notify(new registration_details("Your application number is :- $student_id" ));
    return view('auth.studentregistration4');
}
```

Comment: It looks like `$user` is null.  Shouldn't `User::where('id','=','1')` be using `$student_id`?

Comment: i am sorry could you please make it clear for me tell what to remove and what to add thanks nigel

Comment: Try `$user = User::where('id','=',$student_id)->first();`

Comment: you didn't put student_id in session anywhere in the code shown ... where do you make `session(['student_id' => $request->input('student_id')]);`

Comment: Please try to improve your code style, it's very difficult to read like this.

Comment: the compiler tell me this is the error in this line of code :
    $user->notify(new registration_details("Your application number is :- $student_id" ));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `users` table, the `id` is declared as an `integer` but in your `where` clause you are passing a string.

Try changing this:

```php
...
->where('id', '=', '1')
->first();
...
```

To this:

```php
...
->where('id', '=', 1)
->first();
...
```

Of course, to make this dynamic, replace `1` for a variable like `$user_id`

Also, before you notify the user, make sure that you have indeed a user object:

```php
$user = // get your user
if ( ! is_null($user))
{
    // Make the notification
}
```

Comment: thanks bro ... but it gives me new error which is : syntax error, unexpected 'auth' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in line -> return view('auth.studentregistration4');

Comment: no but i am trying to solve i don't really know what's wrong with syntax

Comment: @HassanAli your view is stored and this name right `resources/views/auth/studentregistration4.blade.php`?

Comment: yeah it's exist no problem on it ...  the problem in the syntax of how i declare the notfy function: $user->notify(new registration_details(Your application number is :- '$student_id' )); 
i know it from the editor .. when the words light as it should